# Power BI Capacity/Tenant/Gateway - where does the data sit and flow?

Tags: powerbi

I have a scenario with Power Bi Premium where it has been very difficult to get a straight answer or find information that answers the question.

Our Power BI tenant is located in Australia, our Power BI Premium capacity is located in Switzerland, our on premise data is located in UK.

When configuring the on-premise data gateway, you are forced to create the connection in the default tenant region, this being Australia.

If you are a Swiss users with a workspace configured to use the Swiss hosted capacity is all data now flowing from UK > Australia > Switzerland Capacity?

Are reports rendering from a swiss user perspective;

- Via the PBI service in Aus using the swiss capacity directly?
- in the same datacentre location as the capacity?

I'm not sure how else to describe it and hope it makes sense. This just seems like a non enterprise ready setup perfornace wise and hope I've miss interpreted what I've been reading.

Thanks

Comment: I have very little experience with **PowerBI** (currently learning more about it) so take this with a grain of salt, but my guess is yes your data would be flowing from UK to Australia to Switzerland in such a scenario (which probably is fine, think of when you visit a website whose server is hosted in another country, there could be multiple hops between your client browser and the server that hosts the website). Reports are **rendered** on the client side, so they would render directly in Switzerland for each user as they run the report (leveraging the data that was sent from the UK server).

Comment: @J.D. Please do not guess at an answer in question comments - it is counter-productive to the site's goals. See the community discussion at https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2811/commenting-on-questions-you-dont-intend-to-answer